# Why does texstudio show different files depending how I open it?

Tags: texstudio

I have texstudio installed on my laptop, and have a shortcut on my desktop as well. If I double click the shortcut, it opens a different .tex file than when I open it via my Windows Search Bar.

I'll give an example: if I open the app via Windows Search, there are three files named X, Y and Z open. But if I double click the icon on my desktop, there's only one file named W open.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Just to make sure: both open the same version of texstudio?

Comment: It appears not. My desktop one is 3.0.1 and windows one is 4.4.1 haha. Then it must be because I once installed it again to update to the newest version. I guess it just installed a copy?

Comment: Yes, if there is a another copy, this explains things. The shortcut on your desktop probably has the path to the old version hard coded, so it will still use the old one.